# how to get value when radiobutton is clicked from list in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services, radio-button

I am newbie to angularjs,I have made a demo in that a list of radiobuttons are there.they are having values related to them,(data is coming from webservice in form of json) now i want to get value related to particular checkbox from list when it is clicked,i got a demo also but still have no luck,can anybuddy please help me?
**js**

```
   app.controller('filterController',  function ($http, $scope, $compile, $filter, $sce)
 {

    var page = gallery.getCurrentPage();
   var Catid = page.options.params;

       var Content ='';
       var areacontent = '';
       var cusinecontent = '';
       var catcontent = '';


       //headers..

       var hdrcuine = '<ons-list-header>'+
          '<ons-row>'+
            '<ons-col>Cuisine'+'</ons-col>'+
            '<ons-col width="35px" style="flex: 0 0 35px; max-width: 35px;">'+
                '<ons-icon icon="ion-android-add-circle" fixed-width="true">'+'</ons-icon>'+
            '</ons-col>'+
          '</ons-row>'+
        '</ons-list-header>';

    var hdrarea =  '<ons-list-header>'+
          '<ons-row>'+
            '<ons-col>Area'+'</ons-col>'+
            '<ons-col width="35px" style="flex: 0 0 35px; max-width: 35px;">'+
                '<ons-icon icon="ion-android-add-circle" fixed-width="true">'+'</ons-icon>'+
            '</ons-col>'+
          '</ons-row>'+
        '</ons-list-header>'; 

var hdrcat =  '<ons-list-header>Categories'+
                '</ons-list-header>'; 

    $scope.areaval = '';
//     $scope.list = {
//        name: '1',
//        intglcode:'0'
//      };
//      
//      $scope.rate={
//          rate:'1',
//          intglcode:'0'
//          
//      };
//      
//      $scope.area={
//          area:'Camana bay',
//          intglcode:'0'
//      };
//      
//      $scope.cusine={
//          cusine:'Pizza',
//          intglcode:'0'
//      };
//      $scope.cat={
//          cat:'Restaurant',
//          intglcode:'0'
//      };
//   

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url:  API_HOST+'/webservice/Get_FilterDetails',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'caymanauth': caymanauth
            },
              data: '&Catid='+Catid

        }).success(function (data) 
            {  


                 for(var i=0; i < data.Details.length; i++){

            //PARSING DATA FOR RATYE TYPES.
            if(data.Details[i] === "Rate Type"){

                for(var d=0;d<5;d++)
                {            


                         $scope.list.intglcode = data.Details[i+1][d]['intGlCode'];



                     console.log("===========my rate types==========="+data.Details[i+1][d]['intGlCode']);

                }    
                   gRate = data.Details[i+1][d]['intGlCode'];

   }
            //PARSING DATA FOR LISTING TYPES.
               if(data.Details[i] === "Listing Type"){
                     for(var d=0;d<5;d++){
                     console.log("===========my Listing types==========="+data.Details[i+1][d]['intGlCode']);
                }

   }
            //PARING FOR AREA
            if(data.Details[i] === "Area"){
                     for(var d=0;d<17;d++){

                         if(areacontent === ''){
                            var val =data.Details[i+1][d]['intGlCode'];
                             areacontent = '<ons-list-item modifier="tappable">'+
          '<label class="checkbox checkbox--list-item">'+
              '<input type="radio" ng-model="areaval" name="area" value={{val}}>'+
            '<div class="checkbox__checkmark checkbox--list-item__checkmark">'+'</div>'+data.Details[i+1][d]['varCityName']+    
          '</label>'+
        '</ons-list-item>';
                         }else{
                               areacontent += '<ons-list-item modifier="tappable">'+
          '<label class="checkbox checkbox--list-item">'+
              '<input type="radio" ng-model="areaval" name="area" value={{val}}>'+
            '<div class="checkbox__checkmark checkbox--list-item__checkmark">'+'</div>'+data.Details[i+1][d]['varCityName']+    
          '</label>'+
        '</ons-list-item>';
                         }
                     console.log("===========my Area types==========="+data.Details[i+1][d]['intGlCode']);
                }

   } 
   //PARSING DATA FRO CUSINE
     if(data.Details[i] === "Cuisine"){
                   for(var d=0;d<7;d++){

                       if(cusinecontent === ''){
                             cusinecontent = '<ons-list-item modifier="tappable">'+
          '<label class="checkbox checkbox--list-item">'+
          '<input type="radio" ng-model="cusine.name" name="cusine" value="Asian">'+
            '<div class="checkbox__checkmark checkbox--list-item__checkmark">'+'</div>'+data.Details[i+1][d]['varName']+
          '</label>'+
        '</ons-list-item> ';
                       }else{
                              cusinecontent += '<ons-list-item modifier="tappable">'+
          '<label class="checkbox checkbox--list-item">'+
          '<input type="radio" ng-model="cusine.name" name="cusine" value="Asian">'+
            '<div class="checkbox__checkmark checkbox--list-item__checkmark">'+'</div>'+data.Details[i+1][d]['varName']+
          '</label>'+
        '</ons-list-item> ';
                       }
                     console.log("===========my cusine types==========="+data.Details[i+1][d]['intGlCode']);
                }

   } 

   //PARSING DATA FOR CATEGORIES
    if(data.Details[i] === "Categories"){
                    for(var d=0;d<14;d++){
                         if(catcontent  === ''){
                             catcontent = '<ons-list-item modifier="tappable">'+
          '<label class="checkbox checkbox--list-item">'+
             +" "+'<input type="radio" ng-model="cat.name" name="cat" >'+
            '<div class="checkbox__checkmark checkbox--list-item__checkmark">'+'</div>'+data.Details[i+1][d]['varName']+
            '</label>'+
        '</ons-list-item>';
                         }else{
                                catcontent += '<ons-list-item modifier="tappable">'+
          '<label class="checkbox checkbox--list-item">'+
             '<input type="radio" ng-model="cat.name" name="cat" >'+
            '<div class="checkbox__checkmark checkbox--list-item__checkmark">'+'</div>'+data.Details[i+1][d]['varName']+
            '</label>'+
        '</ons-list-item>';
                         }
                     console.log("===========my category types==========="+data.Details[i+1][d]['intGlCode']);
                }
   } 
   //return data.Details[i + 1];

}   
Content = hdrarea+areacontent+hdrcuine+cusinecontent+hdrcat+ catcontent;
 $scope.snippet = Content;
            $scope.deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet = function ()
            {
                return $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.snippet);
            };


        }).error(function () {
            alert("error");
        });

 $scope.submitForm = function () {
       alert($scope.areaval);
   };
```

Comment: Where is 'i' defined? Sounds alot like you're only running the code shown after 'i' has finished its loop. Or that only the last 'data.Details' entry is Cuisine.

Comment: @shilly -actually i am really near the solution,but my problem is i dont know how to get value inside javascript,as my html is inside js,Pls see my edit to have idea.

Comment: Can't find an immediate error in the html. Are you sure data.Details contains multiple elements? Since your original question was something like: I only see the last element from data.Details

Comment: sir,i just want to know how to get selected radio value inside "controller"..`http://jsfiddle.net/8kpddb92/4/` ...this way i want to pass value to my radio button.can you pls help me ?

Comment: I have no idea tbh. The example you post contains a directive to create custom elements and a click handler. I don't see any event handlers in your code, so if you don't have a handler, attach it manually or create a directive to create your list items instead of concatenating strings.

Answer (score 0):

I got my solution using `$watch` directive inside the controller,it will return the changed value of $scope variable.Thanks 4 suport